# Half black screen is visible when device orientation changes from portrait to landscape

Tags: swift, xcode, uicollectionviewlayout, collectionview

I'm using InfiniteCollectionView class, Once I change the device Orientation from portrait to landscape, half the screen looks black for a second

I have also tried the `viewWillTransition` function by doing the same but I didn't get success

[image]

Comment: Please add essential code snippets or a minimally reproducible example.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem with a collectionView, I fixed the issue adding this line in the viewWillTransition :

```
self.collectionView.frame = self.view.bounds
```

full function :

```
override func viewWillTransition(to size: CGSize, with coordinator: UIViewControllerTransitionCoordinator) {
    super.viewWillTransition(to: size, with: coordinator)
 let currentList = self.collectionView!.indexPathsForVisibleItems.sorted()
    coordinator.animate { (context) in
        self.setGridOrColumn()
        if (!currentList.isEmpty)
        {
            self.collectionView.frame = self.view.bounds
            self.collectionView!.scrollToItem(at: currentList[0], at: .top, animated: true)
        }
    }
}
```

the function helps the collectionView to be at the same item each time I change the orientation of the device